# How to exclude some folders when using filewatcher in c#?

Tags: c#

everyone, I recently wrote a program wanting to monitor the whole file system. I use FileSystemWatcher class in c#. In order to watch the whole filesystem, I set IncludeSubdirectories to true. However, I also want to exclude three folders in monitoring. I would like to know is there any way to exclude folders? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can only Include, if you need to exclude you would handle that inside of `FileSystemWatcher` Event Handler.

Comment: what do you mean by fired events？ Do you mean whenever a event is fired，like inside onChangehandler， I write a if else statement to exclude the folder I don‘t want？

Comment: @dianedan exactly you would put your code in the event handler to ignore if the condition is met